# Java 8 - Unable to flatMap on stream

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Have a function that returns a `Set<>` I want to apply that function over another collection, create a flattened `Set<>` below is the code snippet with map with just variables renamed

```
 repository.findAll().stream().map(
                p -> forecastService.forecast(p, timeLineInYear, label)
        ).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

`ForecastService` returns `Set<Forecast>` so the above statement returns `Set<Set<Forecast>>`

when I try turning the same statement with a `flatMap`

```
 repository.findAll().stream().flatMap(
                p -> forecastService.forecast(p, timeLineInYear, label)
        ).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

I get an compilation error

> no instance of type variable R exist so that `Set<Forecast>` conforms to
>   `Stream<? extends R>`

Appreciate any help.

Comment: The flatMap call is expecting a Stream, not a Set. Try `p -> forecastService.forecast(p, timeLineInYear, label).stream()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're making it wrong. The `flatMap` method converts your stream of stream -> stream. If you want to accumulate all elements in your Set of Set please consider to use `stream.reduce()`.

Comment: Ísn't this entirely opposite of what scala collection can do, where flatmap flattens your collection and reduce would reduce your collection to a single element. I can see what you have suggested with reduce may still work, but it is, I guess, is still a work around